# Remove elements of one 2D numpy array which are present in another 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 2D numpy arrays as following:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 4], [4, 5], [6, 7]])
b = np.array([[3, 4], [4, 5], [6, 9]])
```

I want to **delete the elements of `a` which are present in `b`** and want the following resultant 2D numpy array

```
Resultant 2D numpy array:
a = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 4], [6, 7]]
```

I wasn't able to find any posts which mention using `numpy.delete` on 2D arrays this way. I would like to avoid for loops as they take too much time to run. I would like to reduce the time complexity as much as possible.

Comment: @Divakar yeah thanks for pointing it out,its difficult to keep track of the question while writing a post on mobile

Comment: No worries, found a duplicate for this one.